# pymongo aggregate with $lookup and pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

I'm using python3, pymongo, mongodb4.4.3

I have two collections:

```
assignments: user_id,qid
questions: qid,text,category
```

When I join them in one query base on qid it looks like this:

```
aggregate = [
        {
            '$match': {
                'user_id': user_id
            }
        },
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'questions',
                'localField': 'qid',
                'foreignField': 'qid',
                'as': 'question'
            }
        }
    ]
result = col_assignments.aggregate(aggregate)
```

And it works perfectly.

But now I need to filter based on 'category' field in 'questions' collection.

Internet says I need to use *pipeline* with *$expr* instead of local and foreign fields. So I did a query like this:

```
aggregate = [
        {
            '$match': {
                'user_id': user_id
            }
        },
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'questions',
                'let': { 'qid': '$qid' },
                'pipeline': [{ 
                    '$match': { 
                        '$expr': {'$eq': ['$$qid', 'qid']},
                        'category': current_category
                    }
                }],
                'as': 'question'
            }
        }
    ]
```

And it won't work, 'question' is empty.

I'm guessing it has something to do with syntax. But I've never used such complex queries neither in mongo shell, nor in pymongo. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Try `'$expr': {'$eq': ['$$qid', '$qid']}`. It seems a `$` is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter out the whole *assignment* item based on corresponding *question* category, you should not define the condition on category inside `$lookup` aggregation stage. Instead use another separate `$match` stage.

```
aggregate = [
        {
            '$match': {
                'user_id': user_id
            }
        },
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'questions',
                'localField': 'qid',
                'foreignField': 'qid',
                'as': 'question'
            }
        },
        {
            '$match': {
                'question.0.category': current_category
            }
        }
])
```

If you want to filter out only the corresponding *question* category, just add missing `$` as [ray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71917182/pymongo-aggregate-with-lookup-and-pipeline#comment127082120_71917182) suggests: `'$expr': {'$eq': ['$$qid', '$qid']}`.

Comment: separate match worked, thanks! didn't know this construction with .0. is possible